# Messing up with branches, old master branch shows files from the new branch?

Tags: git, version-control, github, branch, git-branch

As you can understand I'm still learning Git and how branch works. Anyways:

1. I was working on a local `master` branch.
2. I created and switched to a new `fcwdetection` branch for adding some code, using my IDE, meaning not through the command line.
3. The IDE has asked me to add new files I created (say `A.php`) to the repository. I've added it and modified `B.php` (which was already added).

The **result** is that the `master` branch (I switched back to it) has now `A.php` and `B.php` has the same edits as `B.php` in `fcwdetection` branch.

How is this possible? Is this an error from the IDE or I completely misunderstood how branch work?

Comment: did you committed the two files while in the `fcwdetection` branch?

Comment: @Atropo I don't think so, the IDE has asked me only to "add" it for tracking. I've chosen "Yes" for `A.php` and edited `B.php` as usual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your workflow seems correct. Looks like an error in the IDE. If you want to have the modified files only in the `fcwdetection` branch you should commit them while you're in that branch.
In the command line you do something like that:

Create the branch:

```
git checkout -b fcwdetection
```

Edit `A.php` and create `B.php`
Add all the files, included the new `B.php` to `git`:

```
git add -A .
```

Commit them in the `fcwdetection`:

```
git commit -m 'Commit message'
```

At this point if you check back in `master` you see the old versions of the files:

```
git checkout master
```

If you keep seeing the the modified versions of `A.php` and `B.php` you should check their state, are them already added to the `index`? I say so beause `git` don't let you switch from a branch to another with modified non-commited files, in the command line you get this error:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
[some files]
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.

Aborting
```

Comment: After committing files to `fcwdetection` and switching back to `master` now I see the correct version of `B.php` and `A.php` is removed. That's good. But why the IDE is showing me uncommitted files from `fcwdetection` when I'm working on `master`?! It's so confusing...

Comment: What IDE are you using? The IDE should prevent you from switching to another branch if you have local changes in the files.

Comment: PHPStorm new version 6. Here is what happens: if I edit a file in branch A (without committing anything), when I switch back to branch B I can see the edits. No warnings.

Comment: Looks like a behaviour of the IDE. I prefer to use `git` from the command line :-)